# Using LibreOffice's 'scalc' to convert tab-delimited text to Excel from the command line

Tags: command-line, export-to-excel, libreoffice, csv

I have a LF-terminated, tab-delimited input file that I wish to convert to Excel format (OOXML `.xlsx`, for example) using `scalc --headless`.

I am aware of other options like [pyuno](https://docs.libreoffice.org/pyuno.html), and even some prewritten scripts that are out there like [this one](https://github.com/colonelqubit/libreconverter), but I see no reason to mess with Python in order to accomplish something that I feel certain `scalc` can do with built-in command-line options.

Here's what I've tried that didn't work:

```
scalc --headless --convert-to xlsx input.tsv
scalc --headless --infilter=tsv --convert-to xlsx input.tsv
scalc --headless --infilter=tsv:Text --convert-to xlsx input.tsv
scalc --headless --infilter=Text:tsv --convert-to xlsx input.tsv  # --> Error: no export filter
```

The last two were complete guesses, because, well, there is no real documentation for the `--infilter` option, other than the two examples in the output of `scalc --help`.

The last one produced an error, but in all other cases, the tab character is not recognized as field delimiter, the resulting Excel spreadsheet just has all the data concatenated together in the first column.

#### References

- https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/shared/guide/start_parameters.html

  - specifically, the "[General arguments](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/shared/guide/start_parameters.html#hd_id20161204094429235)" section, which shows two examples:

    ```
    --infilter="Calc Office Open XML"
    --infilter="Text (encoded):UTF8,LF,Liberation Mono,en-US"
    ```

    which I assume indicate conversion from .xlsx to Calc, and converting from plain text to Writer, respectively

Comment: Nowadays, I am not even bothering with LibreOffice for this, due to the lack of concise, readily-available documentation (_e.g._ man pages or ) for the converter options. Instead I am using my own very thin Python wrapper around the openpyxl and [tabulate](https://github.com/astanin/python-tabulate) libraries, which is far from fast, but good enough for most one-off Excel-to-tab-delimited conversions, my typical use case.

Answer (score 2):

Although disappointingly undocumented, I was able to cobble together this working solution from several different sources:

```sh
scalc --headless --infilter="Text - txt - csv (StarCalc):9" \
      --convert-to xlsx input.tsv
```

The "9" is the decimal [ASCII control code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_code_chart) for horizontal tab. I used `python -c 'print(ord("\t"))'` to find this, although `man ascii` would've worked, too.

As detailed [here](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Spreadsheets/Filter_Options#Filter_Options_for_the_CSV_Filter), there are a number of comma-separated options that can be passed to this filter:

```
╔══════════════╤══════════╤═══════════╤═════════════╤══════════════════╤═════════════════════╗
║ option (pos) │ sep. (1) │ quote (2) │ charset (3) │ 1st line (4)     │ cell format (5)     ║
╠══════════════╪══════════╪═══════════╪═════════════╪══════════════════╪═════════════════════╣
║ defaults (?) │ 44 (,)   │ 34 (")    │ 0 (system)  │ 1                │ null ("standard")   ║
╟──────────────┼──────────┼───────────┼─────────────┼──────────────────┼─────────────────────╢
║ example      │ 9 (tab)  │ 39 (')    │ 76 (UTF-8)  │ 2 (skip 1st row) │ 1/9 (skip 1st col.) ║
╚══════════════╧══════════╧═══════════╧═════════════╧══════════════════╧═════════════════════╝
```

So, for example:

```sh
scalc --headless --infilter="Text - txt - csv (StarCalc):9,39,76,2,1/9" \
      --convert-to xlsx input.tsv
```

Would convert a tab-delimited input file with single quotes as text delimiters and UTF-8 encoding to an Excel .xlsx file, skipping the first row and column.

As mentioned above, the input record separator and quote character are the ASCII ordinals. The codes for the character set may be looked up [here](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Spreadsheets/Filter_Options#Filter_Options_for_Lotus.2C_dBase_and_DIF_Filters), but `0` (system default), `1` (Windows-1252), `12` (ISO-8859-1), and `76` (UTF-8) are the interesting ones for English-speakers.

The 5th place in the comma-separated option string, the "cell format," specifies the format for specific columns, and is delimited by forward slashes (`col/fmt/col/fmt`). This is explained in detail [here](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Spreadsheets/Filter_Options#Filter_Options_for_the_CSV_Filter), but briefly:

```
1   Standard
2   Text
3   MM/DD/YY
4   DD/MM/YY
5   YY/MM/DD
6   - (unused?)
7   - ("     ")
8   - ("     ")
9   ignore field (do not import)
10  US-English
    (',' as 1000s sep, '.' as decimal, regardless of locale)
```

There are even *more* values in the filter options string after that, which pertain to various options in the import/export dialog box such as "Quoted field as text." Refer again to the same [OpenOffice wiki article](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Spreadsheets/Filter_Options#Filter_Options_for_the_CSV_Filter) linked above for an explanation of those, because I'm running out of steam here.

#### Sources

- this [Linux Journal article](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/convert-spreadsheets-csv-files-python-and-pyuno-part-1v2) using pyuno, which clued me into the use of `Text - txt - csv (StarCalc)` as the filter name

  - which I corroborated by basically blundering into [this directory](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/core/tree/filter/source/config/fragments/filters/Text___txt___csv__StarCalc_.xcu) in the LibreOffice source tree, where all the filters are defined
- https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Spreadsheets/Filter_Options

  - specifically, [this section](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Spreadsheets/Filter_Options#Filter_Options_for_the_CSV_Filter) for the CSV filter
  - not-so-helpfully marked as "no longer current as of OpenOffice 4.1.x," but current *enough* to still solve my problem
  - this article is what gave me the idea to try the ASCII ordinal for tab as the first character of the "filter options" part of the `--infilter` string
  - that I should use the colon as a delimiter is something I inferred from [this commit](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/core/commit/?id=45ba4d79d968f81f74ef0c4588fd15b1ce91153f) in 2014, which added the two `--infilter` examples to the output of `soffice --help`